# Slim URLFor in version 3

Tags: php, slim

In `Slim v2`, i was able to retrieve the routing for an given get, post, ... requests. I since tinkered with `Slim v3`, can't figure out to recreate the same logic and the documentation is fairly sparse at the moment.

```
$app->get('/login/', function ($request, $response, $args) use($app) {

})->setName('getLogin');

$app->urlFor('getLogin');
```

Which will complain, due to the `urlFor` method is missing, so how do i recreate this code in `Slim v3`? With the error

> "Referenced method is not found in subject class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's  called `pathFor()` now and part of the `router` object.
[Slim Documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-names)

Try

```
$app->router->pathFor('getLogin');
```